# When to use .add() and when to use emit() in Flutter Bloc?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-state

I am new to Bloc in flutter, any one can please explain when should I use add() and when to use emit in Blocs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use emit when you want a new state for your bloc.
Use add when you want your bloc to handle a new event.

See the [Timer](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertimertutorial?id=timerbloc) tutorial as an example.

Answer (score -2):

You should always use `emit`, flutter bloc was upgrade to extends Cubit class and Cubit uses emit. `Add` was old usage.

Comment: I would suggest you to look up this official plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc